# In FFImageLoading how to load an image into memory in Xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android, ffimageloading

Doing this, I believe that my images are only being cached on the disk:

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(item.profileImg)
.DownSample()
.BitmapOptimizations(true)
.LoadingPlaceholder("blank_profile_img.png", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
.Into(holder.imgIcon);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can simply specify the cache type you'd like to use for that particular image, as it's stored against a key.

So an example from one of the times where I use this library is something like:

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(url)
                .WithPriority(LoadingPriority.High)
                .Retry(3, 200)
                .LoadingPlaceholder("ProfilePlaceholder.png", ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                .ErrorPlaceholder("ProfilePlaceholder.png", ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                .WithCache(FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.All)
                .Into(profileImage);
```

The key part is:

```
.WithCache(FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.All)
```

You can specify either `All`, which means it will cache to `IO` and `memory`, or you can select it to just be `IO`, or just be `memory`.

So yours would look something like:

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(item.profileImg)
       .DownSample()
       .BitmapOptimizations(true)
       .LoadingPlaceholder("blank_profile_img.png", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
       .WithCache(FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.Memory)
       .Into(holder.imgIcon);
```

Comment: I ended up using Glide instead however, it performed better